Auto Rig Pro Error with Eyelids
I have encountered an error once I have rigged my characters face. I have positioned all the appropriate markers to where they are supposed to be. Now once I try matching the rig I get this error


This question is off-topic on this site since we are only offering help with problems using Blender and its official addons released with it. Auto-Rig Pro is a paid third-party addon, so please contact the developer about any issues you have.

I face this issue yesterday. I Simply just update the auto rig pro addon the problem is fixed.
